# Query Exchange 2003 contacts via LDAP?

Tags: exchange-2003, ldap

Is it possible to query a public folder contact list in Exchange 2003 via LDAP?  If so, how?

(The Exchange server is on the domain controller in this case)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.
A public folder's contents are only accessible via MAPI.

You can query Exchange's Global Address List via LDAP.

Comment: That isn't really entirely true.  I agree that a public folder cannot be accessed via LDAP, but public folders are accessible via webdav or Exchange web services.

Comment: And don't forget IMAP and NNTP. You can access public folders with those protocols, too. (You won't get all the "contact-ey" goodness of the contacts via those protocols, though...)

Comment: Agreed. I was expecting that, though :-p

Comment: Bummer.  I've got a copier that can only do LDAP and was hoping that we could bring in a public folder contact list.  Thanks guys.